# Add Javascript to DotNetNuke via WebMatrix

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke, webmatrix

I am developing a DotNetNuke site via WebMatrix but cannot figure out how to add javascript to the Home page.

I want to put a jQuery module in there do show a gallery of images but cannot find a way to add the script file and to edit the actual html of the page.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add HTML to a DotNetNuke page, you probably just want to add the HTML module to the page, and edit its content, rather than editing any files directly through WebMatrix.  If you want to change something across the whole site, you can edit the skin files (probably in /Portals/_default/Skins).

To reference a JavaScript file, your best bet is to put it somewhere in your portals folder (e.g. /Portals/0/Scripts/jquery.plugin.js) and then reference it from the page or module header that it applies to (in the Page Settings there is a Page Header Tags setting where you can add a `<script src="/Portals/0/Scripts/jquery.plugin.js"></script>` tag, or in the module settings where's a Header setting).